# Android receiver not called with data/host intent filter

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest, receiver

I have a receiver declared in my `Android Manifest`

```
<receiver
        android:name=".receiver.ConnectionReceiver"
        android:exported="true">

        <intent-filter>

            <data
                android:host="login"
                android:scheme="tisseo.main" />

        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

And I have this receiver class associated:

```
class ConnectionReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {

        Log.d("ConnectionReceiver", "Mais lol")

        StringBuilder().apply {
            append("Action: ${intent?.action}\n")
            append("URI: ${intent?.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)}\n")
            toString().also { log ->
                Log.d("ConnectionReceiver", log)
                Toast.makeText(context, log, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have this HTML page with this link:

```
<a class="submit lienButton" name="login" type="submit" href="tisseo.main://login">LOG IN</a>
```

When I click on it, nothing appended. Even if my application is started or not.

However, if I put my intent filter in an activity, my activity is lauched when I click on my HTML link.

So, what I can do to make my receiver called with my intent-filter host/scheme.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

> what I can do to make my receiver called with my intent-filter host/scheme

That is not possible, except by forcing every Web browser developer to change their apps. Links and similar affordances open activities via an `ACTION_VIEW` `Intent` — they do not send broadcasts.